# Display document names

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using firestore and want to be able to display the document names.
I am trying to display:

gUOqKdpvB8j0yFAJXAdH

iQzM1mlrfBNxrz5E2AeF

lOlaAICvMyPKBaCfseHY

pycbf4Qr9ME3iVkqfRuP

(from the image below)

I can display the collections but not the document names[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRisQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all documents in a collection:

```
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection('fruit').get()                                     
      .then((snapshot) => {
         snapshot.forEach(doc => {
             console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
         });
      })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

Credits to **[Official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)**

Comment: @Neesh If this helped you resolve your issue, could you mark this as an accepted answer for greater visibility to the community? Thanks!